# Wsdl, test web service, newbie

Tags: asp.net, wsdl, httpwebrequest

I have a few wsdl URLs (e.g. https://location?wsdl). And I need to automate the testing of these web services with asp.net. How can I do that ? I was told that http website request could do this (HttpRequest Class). I don't know much about web services except the basics.

Comment: What do you mean by testing the web service? Calling a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a unit test project. Use "Add Service Reference" to reference the WSDLs within this project. Then, just create unit tests to call the service and confirm that the results are as expected.

Note that purists will say these are integration tests, not unit tests, but that's ok. They'll be automated, which is what you were looking for.

Comment: and if I need to test by sending SOAP request message and verify the response ? I still can use approach suggested by you ? Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to manipulate XML? Just use the generated classes to call the service just like it was local. Keep in mind, depending on how complex the service, it may not be practical at all to create the XML "by hand".

Comment: I already have smaple xmls that I know the right xml responses to. What do I do after adding the reference ? Any link to tutorial that will help me out with sending those soap messages ? Thank you.

Comment: Try [How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/).

Answer (score 0):

Soap UI works great if you can get around the requirement of having to using ASP.NET.

See the tutorial here...

http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/your-first-soapui-project.html

If you have to use .NET why can't you just make a proxy class of the webservice using wsdl.exe and then test it with the web service client that's generated from that?